# MVC6/EF7: Seeding Master User and Claims

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm writing a simple MVC6 app using EF7 for the data side, and am running into some problems with setting user and claims. Specifically, I have a database seeding routine to populate the identity tables in the database with a particular user (me) who has specific claims. This seeding method gets called from within startup.cs.

It's pretty simple:

```
    public static async Task CreateMasterUser( UserManager<ApplicationUser> userMgr, ILogger logger )
    {
        var user = await userMgr.FindByEmailAsync("my email");

        if( user == null )
        {
            user = new ApplicationUser()
            {
                Email = "my email",
                FirstName = "blah",
                LastName = "blah",
                UserName = "Blah",
            };

            IdentityResult result = await userMgr.CreateAsync(user, "mypw");

            if( !result.Succeeded )
            {
                logger.LogCritical("Failed to create master user. Messages were: " + String.Join("; ", result.Errors.Select(x => x.Description)));
                return;
            }
        }

        await AddClaim(user, userMgr, "user.add", "allowed");
        await AddClaim(user, userMgr, "user.delete", "allowed");
        await AddClaim(user, userMgr, "user.edit.self", "allowed");
        await AddClaim(user, userMgr, "user.edit.all", "allowed");
        await AddClaim(user, userMgr, "user.confirm", "allowed");
        await AddClaim(user, userMgr, "content.add", "allowed");
        await AddClaim(user, userMgr, "content.view", "allowed");
        await AddClaim(user, userMgr, "content.edit", "allowed");
        await AddClaim(user, userMgr, "content.delete", "allowed");
    }

    private static async Task AddClaim( ApplicationUser user, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userMgr, string claim, string value )
    {
        if( user.Claims.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ClaimType == claim) == null )
            await userMgr.AddClaimAsync(user, new Claim(claim, value));
    }
```

But there's a problem with claims section: every time the site starts up, a new set of claims gets added for me (i.e., duplicate claims are being created for the same user).

When I step through the code, user.Claims never has any entries, even though the database (sql server) shows entries in AspNetUserClaims for the relevant user.

It appears like the Claims collection is not being populated from the database by FindEmailAsync.

How do I make that happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at GetClaimsAsync method of the UserManager.  Explicitly populate your Claims collection.

```
user.Claims = await userMgr.GetClaimsAsync(user);
```

Comment: Thanx! I have a habit of relying on "automatic" lazy loading in EF, or of including "include()" statements in my code when building queries, so I forgot that child table records, like claims, aren't automagically included.